# Uninitialized constant i18n

Tags: rubygems, rails-i18n, i18n-gem, ruby-test

I am trying internalization testing using rspec and hence using i18n gem.

I see that I have the gem installed, but in my test I am looking for the default_locale. I did `puts I18n.default_locale`

I am getting `'Uninitialized constant I18n'` error.

Has anybody faced similar error before?

Comment: just checking , you did require it first, yes?

Comment: yeah it was missing require. I added it in the configuration. I am just playing around i18n to learn using some online examples which itself was missing the require statement. Thanks!!

Comment: Just learning Ruby myself, some of this "obvious" stuff isn't as obvious as other's seem to believe. :(